# Transferring to ftp site using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ftp, sftp

I'm trying to transfer an Excel file to an sftp site and my code executes properly, but I do not see the file on the site.

```
private static void SendFile(string FileName)
{
    FileStream rdr = new FileStream(FileName + ".csv", FileMode.Open);
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://sftp.somesite.com");
    HttpWebResponse resp;
    req.Method = "Post";
    req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UN", "PW", "Domain");

    req.ContentLength = rdr.Length;
    req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
    Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
    byte[] inData = new byte[rdr.Length];
    int bytesRead = rdr.Read(inData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(rdr.Length));

    reqStream.Write(inData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(rdr.Length));
    rdr.Close();
}
```

What am I doing wrong in the code above?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use FtpWebRequest instead?

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public class Ftp
{
  private static void ftpUpload(string filename, string destinationURI)
  {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filename);
        FtpWebRequest reqFTP = CreateFtpRequest(new Uri(destinationURI));

        reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;

        // Specify the command to be executed.
        reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        // use binary 
        reqFTP.UseBinary = true;

        reqFTP.ContentLength = fileInfo.Length;

        // Buffer size set to 2kb
        const int buffLength = 2048;
        byte[] buff = new byte[buffLength];

        // Stream to which the file to be upload is written
        Stream strm = reqFTP.GetRequestStream();

        FileStream fs = fileInfo.OpenRead();

        // Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
        int cLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);

        // Do a while till the stream ends
        while (cLen != 0)
        {
            // FTP Upload Stream
            strm.Write(buff, 0, cLen);
            cLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
        }

        // Close 
        strm.Close();
        fs.Close();
   }
 }
```

Comment: I thought the same exact thing but I received the following error:  "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' to type 'System.Net.FtpWebRequest "

Comment: What namespace is the CreateFTP request? I tried casting it as follows and I still get the same error: FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://sftp.somesite.com" + "/" + Path.GetFileName(filename)));

Answer (score 0):

1. Post doesn't put files. It sends data to server-side scripts.
2. Is that the complete URL? Domain name prepended with "http://" doesn't make a valid URI, which must include a path and the name of the resource.
3. "sftp" in the URL might suggest that SSH File Transfer Protocol (SFTP) must be used, and not FTP or HTTP
4. Who said that uploading to the FTP resource would work this way?

Comment: @Eric It really depends on what server you really have - FTP, SFTP or HTTP. Once you figure this out, you can write correct code. Otherwise it's searching the dark room for a black cat which isn't even there.

Answer (score 0):

As Eugene said in [#3](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/)

When you say "SFTP" do you mean FTP over SSL or SSH File Transfer Protocol. They require different approaches. IF you are indeed using SFTP, as in SSH File Transfer, I think you'd be better off using a third party library (if you can) like sharpSSH.(http://sshnet.codeplex.com/ )

Wiki on SFTP - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: I believe it is sftp judging by the url i was given. Is there any other way besides using a third pary library?

Comment: Unfortunately when I last had to do SFTP transfers with .NET (7 months ago)I didn't find any built-in support from MS. The two 3rd party libs seemed good (also check out SSH.NET  [http://sshnet.codeplex.com/]).